# Разбиение json на списки

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

Как разбить по  json спискам ?

Помогите новичку с json или ткните где описано.

```
{"success":true,"data":{"AER":{"origin":"MRV","destination":"AER","price":2116,"transfers":0,"airline":"UT","flight_number":322,"departure_at":"2020-01-27T08:50:00Z","return_at":"2020-01-29T13:45:00Z","expires_at":"2019-12-23T05:41:33Z"},"BAK":{"origin":"MRV","destination":"BAK","price":4024,"transfers":0,"airline":"J2","flight_number":9718,"departure_at":"2020-05-20T17:40:00Z","return_at":"2020-05-31T16:00:00Z","expires_at":"2019-12-24T10:18:25Z"},"DXB":{"origin":"MRV","destination":"DXB","price":16630,"transfers":1,"airline":"UT","flight_number":574,"departure_at":"2020-02-08T06:00:00Z","return_at":"2020-02-12T16:00:00Z","expires_at":"2019-12-22T06:06:46Z"},"EVN":{"origin":"MRV","destination":"EVN","price":8070,"transfers":1,"airline":"A4","flight_number":258,"departure_at":"2020-02-12T19:20:00Z","return_at":"2020-02-18T17:05:00Z","expires_at":"2019-12-22T23:17:09Z"},"HAN":{"origin":"MRV","destination":"HAN","price":35610,"transfers":2,"airline":"UT","flight_number":374,"departure_at":"2020-01-22T14:00:00Z","return_at":"2020-01-29T08:55:00Z","expires_at":"2019-12-22T04:18:36Z"},"IST":{"origin":"MRV","destination":"IST","price":8032,"transfers":1,"airline":"J2","flight_number":9718,"departure_at":"2020-10-08T17:40:00Z","return_at":"2020-10-11T00:40:00Z","expires_at":"2019-12-24T11:44:50Z"},"LED":{"origin":"MRV","destination":"LED","price":5357,"transfers":0,"airline":"DP","flight_number":540,"departure_at":"2020-01-22T12:10:00Z","return_at":"2020-02-05T08:30:00Z","expires_at":"2019-12-23T21:01:14Z"},"MOW":{"origin":"MRV","destination":"MOW","price":3385,"transfers":0,"airline":"UT","flight_number":574,"departure_at":"2019-12-22T06:00:00Z","return_at":"2020-01-13T17:30:00Z","expires_at":"2019-12-22T06:00:00Z"},"TJM":{"origin":"MRV","destination":"TJM","price":7600,"transfers":0,"airline":"UT","flight_number":510,"departure_at":"2020-01-02T11:10:00Z","return_at":"2020-01-09T08:55:00Z","expires_at":"2019-12-24T10:20:49Z"},"TLV":{"origin":"MRV","destination":"TLV","price":15520,"transfers":2,"airline":"UT","flight_number":274,"departure_at":"2020-02-05T20:40:00Z","return_at":"2020-02-09T05:40:00Z","expires_at":"2019-12-23T17:24:06Z"}},"error":null,"currency":"rub"}
```

Comment: что значит `"разбить на списки"`? что вы хотите получить на выходе?

Comment: AER":{"origin":"MRV","destination":"AER","price":2116,"transfers":0,"airline":"UT","flight_number":322,"departure_at":"2020-02-19T19:50:00Z","return_at":"2020-02-22T13:45:00Z","expires_at":"2019-12-22T17:19:01Z"}  и так далее

Comment: дополните вопрос воспользовавшись кнопкой "править" под вопросом...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import json
arr = ' {"success":true,"data":{"AER":{"origin":"MRV","destination":"AER","price":2116,"transfers":0,"airline":"UT","flight_number":322,"departure_at":"2020-01-27T08:50:00Z","return_at":"2020-01-29T13:45:00Z","expires_at":"2019-12-23T05:41:33Z"},"BAK":{"origin":"MRV","destination":"BAK","price":4024,"transfers":0,"airline":"J2","flight_number":9718,"departure_at":"2020-05-20T17:40:00Z","return_at":"2020-05-31T16:00:00Z","expires_at":"2019-12-24T10:18:25Z"},"DXB":{"origin":"MRV","destination":"DXB","price":16630,"transfers":1,"airline":"UT","flight_number":574,"departure_at":"2020-02-08T06:00:00Z","return_at":"2020-02-12T16:00:00Z","expires_at":"2019-12-22T06:06:46Z"},"EVN":{"origin":"MRV","destination":"EVN","price":8070,"transfers":1,"airline":"A4","flight_number":258,"departure_at":"2020-02-12T19:20:00Z","return_at":"2020-02-18T17:05:00Z","expires_at":"2019-12-22T23:17:09Z"},"HAN":{"origin":"MRV","destination":"HAN","price":35610,"transfers":2,"airline":"UT","flight_number":374,"departure_at":"2020-01-22T14:00:00Z","return_at":"2020-01-29T08:55:00Z","expires_at":"2019-12-22T04:18:36Z"},"IST":{"origin":"MRV","destination":"IST","price":8032,"transfers":1,"airline":"J2","flight_number":9718,"departure_at":"2020-10-08T17:40:00Z","return_at":"2020-10-11T00:40:00Z","expires_at":"2019-12-24T11:44:50Z"},"LED":{"origin":"MRV","destination":"LED","price":5357,"transfers":0,"airline":"DP","flight_number":540,"departure_at":"2020-01-22T12:10:00Z","return_at":"2020-02-05T08:30:00Z","expires_at":"2019-12-23T21:01:14Z"},"MOW":{"origin":"MRV","destination":"MOW","price":3385,"transfers":0,"airline":"UT","flight_number":574,"departure_at":"2019-12-22T06:00:00Z","return_at":"2020-01-13T17:30:00Z","expires_at":"2019-12-22T06:00:00Z"},"TJM":{"origin":"MRV","destination":"TJM","price":7600,"transfers":0,"airline":"UT","flight_number":510,"departure_at":"2020-01-02T11:10:00Z","return_at":"2020-01-09T08:55:00Z","expires_at":"2019-12-24T10:20:49Z"},"TLV":{"origin":"MRV","destination":"TLV","price":15520,"transfers":2,"airline":"UT","flight_number":274,"departure_at":"2020-02-05T20:40:00Z","return_at":"2020-02-09T05:40:00Z","expires_at":"2019-12-23T17:24:06Z"}},"error":null,"currency":"rub"} '
parsed_string = json.loads(arr)
arr1 = parsed_string['data']         // выведет, как написано в комментарии с AER
arr2 = parsed_string['data']['AER']  // выведет данные AER
print(arr1)
print(arr2)
```

Дополнительный вопрос пользователя из комментария:

// Выведет сначала каждый ключ, затем его значение в виде json

```
for k, v in arr1.items():
    print(k)
    print(v)
```

Comment: Ну скажите пожалуйста как еще получить имя первого массива AER потому что он постоянно меняется в завимости от запроса

Comment: Дополнил ответ для каждого массива.